# RewriteRule - how to redirect from wrong to right address

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect such link:

www.website.com/index.phpsite=transport (it's a wrong link which was added to many catalogues of pages etc. and it's really important to redirect from this link to the right one)

to this one (obvious):
www.website.com/index.php?site=transport

All is about the missing "?" in address. 
So I wanted to use .htaccess and RewriteRule, but dunno how.

Can you help me? How to write the rule that will replace wrong link with the working one?

Thanks in advance,
Konrad.

Comment: Try something like RewriteRule ^index.phpsite=transport$ /index.php?site=transport [L]

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for you (although unfortunately I do not have time to fully test the code):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.phpsite=(.*)$ /index.php?site=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

I have used the `.*` wildcard on the end as I wasn't sure if you could have more URL parameters in some URLs you needed to redirect.

All this behaviour is documented in the [related mod_rewrite manual pages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: Your solution initiates 500 Error. Don't know why.

Comment: @KonradKolasa thanks for letting me know. It is now repaired. I accidentally entered `*.` instead of the correct syntax of `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache server, then Write a redirection rule in htaccess file.

> RewriteRule URL1 URL2 [R=301,L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked, this is my answer:

```
RewriteRule ^index.phpsite=transport$ /index.php?site=transport [L]
```